# loki Grafana - promtail install error - page not founded

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki, promtail, fluent-plugin-grafana-loki

## Hi everyone!

I'm trying to install loki grafana, but get the next error:

Page **http://localhost:3100/metrics** is work.
Page **http://localhost:3100/loki/api/v1/push** is not work (page not founded)

---

## promtail-config:

```
\`server:
http_listen_port: 9080
grpc_listen_port: 0

positions:
filename: /tmp/positions.yaml

clients:

- url: http://localhost:3100/loki/api/v1/push

scrape_configs:

- job_name: system
  static_configs:
  - targets:
    - localhost
      labels:
      job: varlogs
      __path__: /var/log/\*log\`
```

## loki-config:

```
\`auth_enabled: false

server:
http_listen_port: 3100
grpc_listen_port: 9096

common:
instance_addr: 127.0.0.1
path_prefix: /tmp/loki
storage:
filesystem:
chunks_directory: /tmp/loki/chunks
rules_directory: /tmp/loki/rules
replication_factor: 1
ring:
kvstore:
store: inmemory

query_range:
results_cache:
cache:
embedded_cache:
enabled: true
max_size_mb: 100

schema_config:
configs:
\- from: 2020-10-24
store: boltdb-shipper
object_store: filesystem
schema: v11
index:
prefix: index\_
period: 24h

ruler:
alertmanager_url: http://localhost:9093\`
```

P.S.
OS Linux

What's my problem?Maybe someone has already solved this problem?

Thank you, everyone!

Comment: P.S. I'm already tryed change port 3100

Answer (score 0):

Try running the command to see if the ingester is working on `http://<server-ip>:3100/ready`